# How to convert windows form library to windows phone library

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-phone, agsxmpp

I have just downloaded agsXMPP SDK from this [link](http://www.ag-software.net/agsxmpp-sdk/) , I opend the source code and I want to build the .dll so it would work for Windows Phone,  since it's made for Winforms.

So is it possible to do so? If so how can I do that?

Comment: It is promoted as **cross platform** and **.NET generic**, so you mustn't have issues with building it in .NET for using for Windows Phone

Comment: Yes but when I open the agsXMPP.dll file in Visual Studio For Windows Phone, it does not open, it generates an error telling me that the reference can not be added because it was not built using Windows Phone Runtime

Comment: Try downloading sources from this page (http://www.ag-software.net/agsxmpp-sdk/download/) and building them yourself in your VS version

Comment: I did download it from that page, I downloaded the first one with the installer

Answer (score 0):

it does not build without modifications for Windows Phone. Sockets are totally different on Windows Phone and other required namespaces are missing. This mean you have to make some major modifications to compile it for WP.
The MatriX SDK which you can download on the same page works fine on Windows Phone.

Comment: Isee, but isn'tthere any other free ope nsource alternatives, because it seem that itisn't the case for Matrix SDK